# Thymeleaf th:class condition

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I wrote this condition and does not work:

```
<fieldset class="rating">
    <span class="course-view-rating bigger">
        <label th:class="${feedback.message.rating &ge; 5}? 'active'" for="rating5"></label>
        <label th:class="${feedback.message.rating &ge; 4}? 'active'" for="rating4"></label>
        <label th:class="${feedback.message.rating &ge; 3}? 'active'" for="rating3"></label>
        <label th:class="${feedback.message.rating &ge; 2}? 'active'" for="rating2"></label>
        <label th:class="${feedback.message.rating &ge; 1}? 'active'" for="rating1" ></label>
    </span>
</fieldset>
```

The value of `feedback.message.rating` is always a number from 0 to 5.

Using:

- Spring 4.3
- Java 1.8
- Thymeleaf 3.0.7***

This is the error message:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [thymeleafDispatcherServlet] in context with path [/frontend-th] threw exception 
    [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: 
    Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "feedback.message.rating ? 1" (template: "pages/eventdetail" - line 179, col 52)] with root cause
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot handle (8805) '?'
```

Thanks for the response

Comment: Welcome to SO! Stack Overflow is for specific and answerable questions. Please can you review this and amend: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try this one,

```
<label th:class="${feedback.message.rating} >= 5 ? 'active'" for="rating5"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working and i don't understand why :D :D

`<label th:class="${feedback.message.rating >= 5}? 'active'" for="rating5"></label>`